# Multi-part identifier error when trying to create a trigger on insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-server-2012, sql-insert

I am trying to update a table whenever a new row is inserted into another table.

When a row is added to the `storeRoutes` table, I want this trigger to update a column in my `productList` table.  It should set the column `isAvailable` to 0 (false) using the `storeProductId` column from the new row inserted into `storeRoutes`.

Here is my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [setIsAvailableFalse]
    ON [storeRoutes]    
    AFTER INSERT
    AS  BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;     

    UPDATE productList
    SET isAvailable = 0     
    WHERE productId = Inserted.storeProductId

END
```

But I keep getting an error:

> multi-part identifier, 'Inserted.storeProductId' could not be bound.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use a `DEFAULT` constraint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `select` from pseudo-table `inserted`:

```
UPDATE pl 
SET isAvailable = 0     
FROM productList pl
INNER JOIN Inserted i ON pl.productId = i.storeProductId
```

You could also use `exists`:

```
UPDATE pl 
SET isAvailable = 0     
FROM productList pl
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Inserted i WHERE  pl.productId = i.storeProductId)
```

Comment: Hi thanks! I am getting an error for the first solution you suggested...`Incorrect syntax near WHERE` but I just copied and pasted what you wrote out.  All the table and column names are correct.

Comment: Thanks I get a warning from SQL Server saying, `about to execute an UPDATE statement without a WHERE`

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell: that's just a warning. The join ensures that only the relevant row(s) get updated, so nothing to worry about.