# Trigger to update table value after inserting new row on other table

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, triggers

I have two tables 1 for journeys and other for enrollments for the journeys .. foreach journey there is a limited number of seats .. I want to create a trigger the reduces the number of seats for a journey when someone enrolled in .

- TABLE journey includes (Journey_ID(PK),Seats,Price)
- TABLE Enrollment includes (Enrollment_ID(PK),Journey_ID(FK))

Code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
ON Enrollment
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Journeys
    SET Seats = Seats -1    
    FROM inserted t1 
    INNER JOIN Journeys ON t1.Journeys_ID = Journeys.Id
END
GO
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65328245/2029983) looks oddly similar.

Comment: @Mario what questions do you have after reading the link Larnu provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You going to need two triggers. Insert Enrollment(decrease seats available) and Delete Enrollment(increase seats available)
Use SELECT COUNT(*) because the inserted can return 0, 1 or more rows. The same for DELETED.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[EnrollmentInsert]
ON  [dbo].[Enrollment]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE Journeys
    SET Seats = Seats - IsNull((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INSERTED WHERE INSERTED.Journeys_ID = Journeys.Id), 0)    
    FROM Journeys
    JOIN INSERTED ON INSERTED.Journeys_ID = Journeys.Id
END
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[EnrollmentDelete]
ON  [dbo].[Enrollment]
AFTER DELETE
AS 
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE Journeys
    SET Seats = Seats + IsNull((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DELETED WHERE DELETED.Journeys_ID = Journeys.Id), 0)    
    FROM Journeys
    JOIN DELETED ON DELETED.Journeys_ID = Journeys.Id
END
GO
```

Comment: You can easily simplify that by combining into a single trigger and update statement. And you don't need a subquery when you have a join.

Comment: It is also an option, but its uses more resources. In order to UPDATE the COLUMN SEATS, it should count(*)  Enrollments on every insert and update.